# Customize existing menu items

Tags: eclipse, swt

Is there a possibility to customize existing menu items.

For example, setting a tool tip to Window -> Editor -> Toggle Split Editor

Comment: It is probably possible by writing a plug-in, otherwise no.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to write a new plugin for which I need to provide a tool tip for existing menu items.